# What does int foo(a) int a; { return a } mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax, function-declaration

While investigating [function declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) I came across a strange (to me) way of function definition:

```
int f(void); // declaration: takes no parameters
int g(); // declaration: takes unknown parameters
 
int main(void) {
    f(1); // compile-time error
    g(2); // undefined behavior
}
 
int f(void) { return 1; } // actual definition
int g(a,b,c,d) int a,b,c,d; { return 2; } // actual definition
```

This last line completely confused me. What does `int g(a,b,c,d) int a,b,c,d; { return 2; }` mean?
Such a question probably has already been asked, but I have no clue how to comprise a search query.

Comment: That's deprecated syntax that should not be used.

Comment: These are simply dummy functions, where they are just testing variables and demonstrating how you can create functions and modify their inputs later - the function `g`, once edited, takes in the four parameters (_as ints, hence the definition_) and returns 2 as a dummy number - those variables are being inputted for no reason other than to demonstrate. You could even say: `int g(a,b,c,d) int a,b,c,d; { return a*b*c+d; }` just to mess around.

Comment: It means that `g` takes 4 parameters, are they are all `int`s.  It also means that the code was written in 1978 or by someone continuing to use extremely out of date syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `g` uses the old K&R method of specifying argument types.

Rather then specifying the the arguments and their types inside of `(` and `)`, only the names are specified, then the types of the arguments are specified, then the function body.

This style of declaring parameters is deprecated and should no longer be used, as it does not also qualify as a function prototype among other reasons.